# Make html list 100% height with borders

Tags: html, css

I need to make a list 100% height, and each list item 20%. I was able manage this. But when adding a border at the bottom of each list item, the list becomes more than 100% height and scrollbar appears.

How to make a list with borders fit the the screen height ?

```css
html,body {height:100%; margin:0;}
.list {
    width: 200px;
 height:100%;
}
.list ul {
 height:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 list-style: none;
}
.list ul li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000; /* Scrollbar appears with this*/
 height:20%;
}
.list ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 1em 1em 1em 0.2em;
 color:#000;
}
.list ul li a:after 
{
    content:"»";
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
 <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `.list ul li` :

`box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :

```css
html,body {height:100%; margin:0;overflow:hidden;}
.list {
    width: 200px;
 height:100%;
}
.list ul {
 height:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 list-style: none;
}
.list ul li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 height:20%;
}
.list ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 1em 1em 1em 0.2em;
 color:#000;
}
.list ul li a:after 
{
    content:"»";
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
 <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body {height:100%; margin:0;}
.list {
    width: 200px;
 height:100%;
}
.list ul {
 height:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 list-style: none;
}
.list ul li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000; /* Scrollbar appears with this*/
    box-sizing:border-box;
 height:20%;
}
.list ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 1em 1em 1em 0.2em;
 color:#000;
}
.list ul li a:after 
{
    content:"»";
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
 <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: IE8 do not support `box-sizing` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-sizing` property.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```